# How to export custom TexStudio shortcut and macro?

Tags: macros, texstudio, keyboard

Since I usually re-install, either the OS or TexStudio. It's frustrated to configure everything again.

I save the profile and restore but those information were not in there.

Comment: Please give more details related to how you saved and (attempted to) restored and what information was missing.

Comment: Normaly the macros and shortcuts are part of the profile that you can export. So, as @verdammelt said, some more information are necessary ...

Comment: @verdammelt Option> Save profile and when re-install Option> Load Profile. 
What I lost were: (1) customize shortcut, e.g. I use Alt+Shift+Down to dupplicate lines, or whatever (2) Defined macros, e.g. Shift+F1 for insert a customized figured environment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These settings are stored in [texstudio.ini](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Where_are_the_settings_stored.3F). You may also copy the whole folder which contains it.

Comment: I found those information in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\texstudio.ini`. Thanks!

Comment: In Ubuntu I found the file in `~/.confg/texstudio`.

Comment: Also Ubuntu 18.04.4 for me it was `~/.config/texstudio`. (Don't know whether the missing i in the comment above is a typo or due a different version of texstudio or ubuntu.)

Comment: Is the issue really that simple. The question idoes not explicitly say so but often we want to transfer our shortcuts because we installed a new DIFFERENT version of texstudio. I just replaced `texstudio.ini` in `~/.config/texstudion` on my new laptop after installing `TeXstudio 2.12.22 (2.12.22+debian-1build1)` with my old .ini file but it is not detecting any of the custom shortcut settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kvothe:  I have same problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something mysterious is going on, if I simply copy the `texstudio.ini` from old folder to new folder, the new TexStudio does not recognize my macros -- perhaps it is a version issue, but I doubt it.

Here's the trick that worked for me:

1. On the new TexStudio, create a new macro.
2. Then save the macro.
3. You will find a new folder named `~/.config/texstudio/macro`.
4. Now exit TexStudio.
5. Delete the `macro` folder and its contents.
6. Modify the `texstudio.ini` file to insert your macros there, the old way.
7. Now start TexStudio again.  Your macros should appear.

Now there's a "save macro" function which allows you to save to the `macro` folder, but it saves only one macro at a time and you have to go through them all.  After that, you have them in a more official format, easier to transfer next time, I guess.