# Bulk-Export Macros in TeXstudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, import, export

I have a collection of macros that I use. I want to export them, then import them on another computer.

> I'm looking for some way to *bulk-export* my macros.

There are two highly-related questions, but unfortunately neither solves my issue.

- [Export and import macro files in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466243/export-and-import-macro-files-in-texstudio?rq=1)
- [How to export custom TexStudio shortcut and macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153947/how-to-export-custom-texstudio-shortcut-and-macro)

The first one only allows me to export a single macro at a time. That's super boring, as I have quite a few. (I guess I could set up and AutoHotKey macro to export my TeXstudio macros!)

The second claims that the macros are stored in `texstudio.ini`. This doesn't appear to be the case. The post is from 2014, though, so maybe it was true then, but isn't now. Looking in this `.ini` file, I can see that my macros simply aren't in there. Moreover, I did try copying the `.ini` file over anyway, backing up the old one, but it didn't work. Additionally, I want to move to a newer version of TeXstudio; the `.ini` file includes in it the version used, so doesn't seem safe to be using it on a different version.

---

Dhruv suggests a method which *almost* works. I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work, but I have a fix. The macros look fine, including having the correct shortcut. However, I had to go onto `Configure TeXstudio... --> Shortcuts --> Macros`. All the keyboard shortcuts show there. I had to simply double-click on the command under `Current Shortcut`, then hit `Enter`. I'd sometimes get a warning saying that the shortcut is already assigned elsewhere. I just hit `Enter`/`Ok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder where you find the `texstudio.ini` file there will be a folder called 'macros'. You can copy this folder and paste it into your new installation. I haven't tried it but I think it should do the job.

Cheers.

P.S. If you don't mind sharing the macros that you have made, consider sharing them with the community.

Comment: That *almost* works. And I should have spotted this folder! It correctly fills in the "shortcut" and everything. But when I hit the shortcut, nothing happens! Eg, `Ctrl+I` in my case should give `\textit{`, without any closing `}`. To emphasise, *nothing happens*. Not even the old `\textit{}` with the cursor between the `{}` happens. I've tried closing and reopening. Somewhat confusing. Also, I would share the macros, but they're super boring. Eg, `Ctrl+E --> \emph{`

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your macros window in TexStudio?

Comment: I realised that my previous comment was wrong, so deleted it. I did have to do a little more work. I've edited my original question to describe the very simple step I had to do.